# Disastorous biosignal amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

[image: Biosignal amplification circuit]

I built this circuit on a breadboard, connected a house plant and 12 volt DC. Not many seconds later magic smoke appeared from all ic's except the in128. I cannot see the error. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you didn't connect power backwards?

Comment: If you mean for the amps then I am certain

Comment: Aside from the power mistake, do you really want to ADD the high pass and low pass signals?  Those should probably be daisy-chained.

Comment: @coffeeandcigarettes Can you add information about the power supply to your question? That is the only thing common to all the ICs. It's overwhelmingly probable that that's where the problem is.

Comment: I'm a bit worried by all the capacitive loads and antennas you have connected to the output of the first op-amp.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Do you mean by the power mistake my mistake to apply positive feedback at U2 - the virtual ground?

By daisy-chaining do you mean to remove the summer? I used the band stop example from electronics-tutorials.ws https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/fil133.gif

Comment: @vofa I used 12 volt DC with ground at VEE. Spesifically I used an AC to DC battery eliminator.

Comment: That tutorial is simply not applicable.  They were shooting for a band reject, and you want (presumably) a band pass. (Unless you're trying to just remove 60Hz, but that isn't the best approach -- you want to only pass frequencies of interest)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

*Figure 1. The half-supply ground reference circuit is wrong.*

You have designed this incorrectly and are applying positive feedback to U2 instead of negative. The LM358 inputs should be swapped. This may not be the reason for your trouble but it can't be helping.

You have drawn the circuit badly and this makes the scheme of what the circuit is doing difficult to decipher. With a better layout you would probably have spotted the error yourself. The typical layout is shown below. Note how higher voltages are generally to the top and lower voltages to the bottom.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYHZaP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Standard half-supply circuit.*

Note that in this layout it is immediately obvious that the non-inverting input is at half supply and that the output is the ground.

Your circuit has C2 and C3 coupled to the op-amp output but this will drive any noise on the supply onto the output so it's not a good idea. Decide which power rail is going to be your reference and tie the capacitor C1 to that rail. This means that if the supply voltage sags the voltage between Vee and your GND will remain constant. C1 looks too small and I would expect something more like 10 to 100 uF in there.

I would expect your error to drive the GND output to Vee. Why this would cause the chip to overheat is not clear to me at this time. Reverse power rails is the most likely cause.